# "Structure needs cleaning" when mounting newly created ext4 partition

Tags: mount, hard-drive, disk, partitioning

I had problems with mounting my external HDD disk (WDC WD20EURX-63T0FY0)

I did not care about the data there, so I recreated MBR and created EXT4 partition. However, in about 70% of cases I'm not able to mount partition, because `mount` command results in:

```
sudo mount -a 
mount: /media/myExistingMountDirectory: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.
```

Then I reboot system and try again. Succeeded in 3 attempts out of 10.

My first guess was physical disk corruption. Disk was used a lot for some time now (3.2y total power-on time). SMART shows following interesting info:

```
Spin_Up_Time      4225
Start_Stop_Count  2481
Power_On_Hours    28068
All errors        0
```

However, I ran extended SMART test with result `Completed without error`.

Same thing happens if disk layout is GPT, so this is not an issue.

Does it mean the disk is broken or am I doing something wrong with mounting it?

Comment: Why MBR? Why not GPT?  You're real close to the limits of what MBR can do. https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Drive_Partition_Limits_Fact_Sheet.pdf

Comment: I agree with @K7AAY. This should have a GPT partition table.

Comment: @K7AAY I agree with both of you - and I've also tried to do it with GPT layout, with same result. So this is not an issue here.

Comment: Please describe *exactly* how you created the partition and the file system, and how you tried to mount it.

Comment: @sudodus I did it using GParted in a proper manner. I'm trying to mount it using `sudo mount -a` or just automatic mount from Ubuntu UI.

Comment: I guess the drive is in `/etc/fstab`. Otherwise it would not work with `sudo mount -a`. I cannot see anything wrong with what you are doing, or any indication of a drive failure except that it fails to mount 7 attempts of 10. -- Maybe some physical sector is near failure, so that read attempts will succeed sometimes but now always. - Maybe the power supply is near failure or you are straining it with too many devices, so that the voltage is not quite high enough for the drive to work correctly. - Maybe the RAM is flaky, it can cause many strange symptoms. You can test overnight with memtest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I believe **the disk was corrupted**, I threw it away and replaced by other, working fine using same configuration.